# Is confidence interval useful for some data not belonging to a known distribution

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, density-estimation

I am not even sure if my question is stupid. I have a vector of around 1000 values. The density chart of my data is like this:

```
ggplot(data=a,aes(x=Prob)) + geom_density()
```

[image]

We can see my data does not conform to any distribution. Now, I want to use a method like confidence interval to decide which values are statistically suspicious. For example, if some criterion is higher or lower than a value, then some data is statistically significant. But I do not know if confidence interval is OK when the data does not belong to any distribution. And if I cannot use confidence interval in this case, what else is suitable?

Comment: You need to define a statistic based on which you will judge if there's something "interesting" in the data or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have probability on the X-axis; probability of what? Maybe a confidence interval makes more sense on the original scale of the data.

Also, you say that your data does not seem to conform to any distribution, but might it perhaps follow a zero-inflated Poisson distribution?

You can always obtain non-parametric confidence intervals through bootstrapping.